# Why is the string that I constructed rendered as escaped HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to add a link to each element of an array, then join the resulting array. I tried:

```
myarray.collect{|u| link_to u[:first_name], username_path(u[:username])}.join(', ')
```

This does everything correctly, except it returns:

```
&lt;a href=&quot;/niels&quot;&gt;Niels Bohr&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href=&quot;/richard&quot;&gt;Richard Feynman&lt;/a&gt;
```

Instead of

```
<a href="/niels">Niels Bohr</a>, <a href="/richard">Richard Feynman</a>
```

How do I fix this? Or is there a simpler way of proceeding?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `html_safe`

```
myarray.collect{|u| link_to u[:first_name], username_path(u[:username])}.join(', ').html_safe
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with adding the links or joining the elements of the list. That all works fine. What is wrong is that your string is considered *unsafe* and some of the characters used to construct valid HTML (and more importantly, javascript) are being escaped.

As fl00r says, you should add 
`.html_safe` after the string, to tell the rendering function that any HTML in the function can be safely sent to the browser as-is.